# Cannot run pyspark in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, jupyter

I have Windows 10 and have installed spark following the instructions from:

https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/apache-spark-installation-on-windows-10/

Now I open my jupyter notebook, and type the following:

```
import os
import sys

# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="c:\\Spark"

# Append pyspark  to Python Path
sys.path.append("C:\\Spark")
sys.path.append("C:\\Spark\\python")
sys.path.append("C:\\Spark\\python\\lib")
sys.path.append("C:\\Spark\\python\\lib\\py4j-0.9-src.zip")

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
```

and seems that cannoot load the accumulators library, as I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-54-68cce399fff2> in <module>()
     12 sys.path.append("C:\\Spark\\python\\pyspark")
     13 
---> 14 from pyspark import SparkContext
     15 from pyspark import SparkConf
     16 

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\__init__.py in <module>()
     39 
     40 from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
---> 41 from pyspark.context import SparkContext
     42 from pyspark.rdd import RDD
     43 from pyspark.files import SparkFiles

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\context.py in <module>()
     26 from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
     27 
---> 28 from pyspark import accumulators
     29 from pyspark.accumulators import Accumulator
     30 from pyspark.broadcast import Broadcast

ImportError: cannot import name accumulators
```

These is how my sys.path looks like, which I assume are the correct folders:

```
['',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Anaconda2',
 'c:\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg',
 'c:\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\Manuel\\.ipython',
 'C:\\Spark',
 'C:\\Spark\\python',
 'C:\\Spark\\python\\lib',
 'C:\\Spark\\python\\lib\\py4j-0.9-src.zip',
 'C:\\Spark\\python\\pyspark']
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by installing winutils.exe as described in

[Resolving Spark 1.6.0 "java.lang.NullPointerException, not found](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/02/09/resolving-spark-1-6-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-not-found-value-sqlcontext-error-when-running-spark-shell-on-windows-10-64-bit/)